# Reputation needed to post a comment is too high

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, reputation

I, being a small rep "stackexchangee" (I am not even sure if that's the right word), often find myself missing out in answering questions as I cannot comment. This is since the rep required to answer a question is too high: **50** (currently at 46).

Commenting is really important since I can ask for clarification from the OP and then hopefully answer his question. I am pretty sure sure a bot cannot get 10 or more reps hence no need for a high reputation requirement.

So is there a good reason for it being 50 and not let's say … **10**?

Comment: That's rather a question for the main Meta site (nothing a "local site" can do something about). But before you post there, that was already done multiple times. Please see e.g.: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/192154) and [Lower commenting threshold to 1 rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71368/192154).

Comment: I agree, the threshold is too high.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: let's decrease it to 25.

And I encourage especially the high-rep users (like and including me) to vote more on new user's questions.

### References

This issue has been discussed on the Main Meta site already, e.g. in [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/192154) and [Lower commenting threshold to 1 rep.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71368/192154) as pointed out by [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy) in the comments.

The suggestions there are good for programming issues, because

1. in many cases, a programmer can narrow down the options and then even describe 3 alternative possibilities and solve them all in his answer.
2. there are enough questions on Stack Overflow to gain reputation

### Analysis

Above 2 assumptions do not apply to this site.

1. In many cases, we cannot narrow down potential options. It would just be a guess, not a "scientific" approach.
2. we don't have as many questions here.

### Why 25?

I could bet everyone runs 2 software applications on his PC that are a bit unusual. Put those into a good (!) question, as if you were still looking for those. Then self-answer the question. If that works well, you should at least get 1 upvote on each question and answer, making 30 in total. Even with a downvote or two, you could still comment.

### Other options

Find a topic in which you're good at. Ideally it's one of the bigger SE sites such as Stack Overflow or SuperUser. Hopefully you can get 200 reputation there and then benefit from the +100 trust bonus on any other site.

Comment: Voting too much may cause your account to be banned or deleted. (http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1117/903)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: voting too much? a) there's a limit. b) there's even a badge for voting much